# entitydatasource one to many to one

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, one-to-many, edmx, entitydatasource

I am trying to build a drop down list with an entitydatasource and a query. I am recieving the following error message, I am unsure about what I am doing wrong:

> 'UserId' is not a member of 'Transient.collection [WebAppModel. UserSite(Nullable=True, DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 69.

Entity Data Source

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsSites" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="name=WebAppEntities" 
                DefaultContainerName="WebAppEntities" 
                EntitySetName="Sites" 
                Include="Sites, UserSites" 
                Where="EXISTS(SELECT Sites.SiteId, Sites.Domain FROM Sites 
                            WHERE UserSites.UserId=@UserId)">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**edm(Site) - Table(Sites)**

- SiteId - PK
- List item
- Organisation
- FirstName
- LastName
- Domain
- Address1
- Address2
- City
- State
- Postcode
- CountryId
- Phonenumber
- Email

**edm(UserSite) - Table(UserSites)**

- UserId FK
- SiteId FK

Comment: I dont think that post really relates to my question?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved!

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsSites" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="name=WebAppEntities" 
                                    DefaultContainerName="WebAppEntities" 
                                    EntitySetName="Sites"
                                    Where="EXISTS(SELECT VALUE u FROM it.UserSites AS u WHERE u.UserId = @UserId)" EnableFlattening="False" Select="it.[SiteId], it.[Domain]">
                                    <WhereParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" DbType="Guid" />
                                    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```